# Is this use of up to correct?

Tags: prepositions

I came across this doubt.

If I want to say, for example.

> "This inventor is a genius, he can create from a simple chair up to a
> sophisticated car engine"

Is that correct?
I don't know how to use the prepositions when you want to use that expression. another example.
"I eat everything from the worst of the meals up to a delicious pizza"

I know the structure but I wonder if I am using these prepositions wrong.

I searched on the internet but couldn't find this, so I came here to ask you guys.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No need for up: create **anything from a simple chair **to an x.  up to is for setting a limit in measurements or numbers.

Comment: You got what some refer to as a comma splice there...BTW...do you consider pizza to be _hauteur cuisine_...?

Comment: @Cascabel on parle de _la haute cuisine_, je pense.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, you are _highestly write_... LOL  I actually wrote _haute_... blame it on fickn auto-correct, and my distraction at the time. TXS.

Comment: Note that Lambie added a noun: create *anything* from a simple chair, instead of create from.

Comment: thx buddies for the feedback, appreciate it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatically correct but it's a little unusual.

In this context "up to" indicates the top limit of what you are talking about ("top" being metaphorical of course). So your phrase is correct - the top limit of what the inventor can create is a 'sophisticated car engine'. The bottom limit is 'a simple chair'.

The reason "up" is unusual is that it is not necessary. You specify the two limits of what the inventor can create - at the lower end a simple chair, at the upper end a sophisticated car engine. As long as the reader understands that a chair is simpler than a car engine, then you don't need to tell them which is the upper limit and which is the lower limit.

> from a simple chair to a sophisticated car engine

works perfectly well, and would be the normal way to say it. Adding "up" adds no value.

If you didn't specify the lower limit then "up" is necessary:

> he can create anything up to a sophisticated car engine

Comment: amazing feedback! thanks buddy, it helped a lot, hope you have a nice day ^^